# Does Judge R Dearie have to quit the bench to accept a special master job?

Tags: united-states, judge

Any truth to the assertion that a SENIOR status judge is prevented from taking “outside employment”?

Comment: How is a Federal judge doing a Federal judicial task “outside employment”?

Comment: Can you cite a reputable source for this "assertion" please.

Comment: @rick, just heard it from my son-in-law who works for a federal judge that is on senior status. I’m not asking if he is telling me the truth, so the source is unimportant, rather I’m asking the community if some has experience with this situation

Answer (score 2):

[FRCP 53](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_53) states the only rule of disqualification for special masters:

> (a)(2) A master must not have a relationship to the parties,
> attorneys, action, or court that would require disqualification of a
> judge under 28 U.S.C. §455, unless the parties, with the court's
> approval, consent to the appointment after the master discloses any
> potential grounds for disqualification.

The rule also states that

> A magistrate judge is subject to this rule only when the order
> referring a matter to the magistrate judge states that the reference
> is made under this rule

meaning that "being a judge" is not a bar to serving as a special master. He is a retired judge, so there is no bar arising from [federal court employment ethics rules](https://www.uscourts.gov/sites/default/files/vol02c-ch10.pdf). Since the DoJ also proposed retired judges for this position, we can be pretty sure that it's legal to appoint a retired judge to be special master.

Comment: Thank you for that answer , however you have referred to justice Dearie as “retired” but as I understand it he is not   “Retired”  , but simply placed on “Senior status”, meaning he has a reduced work load for the Brooklyn court.

Comment: I think the concept of "retirement" is not as absolute in the judiciary as it is in industry, and it's more like in academe.

Comment: @BobE Retiring from the bench means you do not currently preside in any cases and can not take new cases, but you can at any time return to being an *active* judge, for example by being voted to be a district's judge again.

Comment: @Trish .- from Wiki (with references) perhaps this addresses your comment: "He took senior status on April 3, 2011, and was succeeded by Judge Pamela K. Chen in March 2013.[8] He remained an active judge on the Eastern District Court; according to a court official, he is planning to go on inactive status at the end of 2022.[9]